# Rails validate state if account is active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, state-machine

the user of the app have to ativate there account before the can edit or delete the entry.

How can i set the state from inactive to active?
I'm using the state_machine from pluginaweek to set the states.

```
state_machine initial: :inactive do
event :activate do
    state = 'active'
  end
end
```

My controller called the activate-action will send via email to the user.

```
def activate
@entry = Entry.find([:id])
if (check_email_link(@entry.exp_date))
  if @entry.save
    flash[:notice] = t("activate")
    redirect_to @entry
    else
      flash[:error] = t("already_activated")
      redirect_to @entry
  end 
else
  flash[:error] = t("timeout")
  redirect_to @entry.new
end
```

end
the documentation say that i can set the Städte via entry.state but rhis won't work.

Why will the entry not activated? Can every help me?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`state_machine`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)?

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. The docu said entry. state I can set the state. But this won't work

Comment: Does there any error log for the operation? Or try the method in rails console e.g. `@user.activate ` and check does it work or any error. I've used [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) and meet issue [#261](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/261) and [#334](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/334). The solution is changing the gem, using [state_machines-activerecord](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-activerecord) instead.

Comment: No i don't get any errors. The other question is, have I to use the attribute update function? If yes why do I need the state_machine. The initial state I set to inactive. That works fine.

Comment: You should call `activate` for **model instance** (in your sample code is @user or @entry), not controller method.

Comment: Now i've the problem in my head. Is it a good solution to call action in the model? I think that is the job for the controller? The user get the mail with the link to the controller action. What is the advantage to call a method for the model? I'll try it this evening, when the child sleep ;-) thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you setup [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#activerecord), it's adding some method to the ActiveRecord(abbr. AR) model according to your code.

for example:(just demo code, maybe some typo |||)

```
# setup state_machine for model Entry
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine initial: :inactive do
    event :activate do
      transition :inactive => :active
    end
  end
end
```

then state_machine setup method `activate` for you.

If your operate in rails console

```
# Create an instance of Entry, you will see the attribute `state` value is "inactive" as your setting.
@entry = Entry.create
#=> {:id => 1, :state => "inactive"}

# Then use the method `activate` state_machine define for you according your setting. You will see `state` been changing to "active".
@entry.activate
#=> (sql log...)
#=> {:id => 1, :state => "active" }
```

That's the sample usage of state_machine gem, state_machine help you manage state of data model, not controller.

So, your code may like this:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_routes_that_activate_user
    # (some logic...)
    @entry.activate
  end
end
```

Hope this could you :)

Comment: Your answer @gaga5lala was very helpful. That is so easy to use. I had only line to change. `
`event :activate do
**transition :inactive => :active**
end`

Comment: @amarradi oops, I didn't notice there's syntax error of state_machine usage. Thanks for reminding, I  fixed it in my answer!

Comment: That's no syntax error but the first way doesn't work for me. Why did I get -1 for my question? What can I do better?

Comment: @amarradi Sorry for the late reply. I don't know why there's an down vote of your question, but I guest maybe someone misunderstood that it's just a question without reading state_machine document.